# Change ownership of mounted ftp directory and change permissions

Tags: linux, ftp, centos7, mount

i've a FTP drive on my qnap and i want to mount on a my centos.

So i edit /etc/fstab with this line :

```
curlftpfs#192.168.1.80/Backup /opt/tafazzi87/backup fuse defaults,exec,uid=tafazzi87,gid=tafazzi87,umask=002 0 0
```

i want that user `tafazzi87` will be the owner of this folder and he can read and write on this volume.

so with this line on fstab now i've this situation :

```
drwxrwxr-x.  1 tafazzi87 tafazzi87  1024  1 gen  1970 backup
```

but if i try to enter on this folder with cd command i've this error :

```
[tafazzi87@localhost ~]$ cd /opt/tafazzi87/backup 
-bash: cd: backup: Permission denied
```

Why i've this error?Where i'm wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Can root get there?

Comment: yes with root i can read, write and enter on that folder

Comment: Well, the only thing I can think of is selinux, what does `getenforce` say? When you try to enter the directory, does it log something to `/var/log/audit/audit.log`. Does it work when you enter permissive mode (`setenforce 0`)?

Comment: i've already try to disabled selinux but nothing change